# How to extract URL links using UiPath Studio

Tags: uipath-studio

I am using UiPath Studio(2022.4.3) for data scraping, I don't find "Data Scraper" tool, instead there is this tool called "Table Extraction". How do I extract URL links found in Web pages/Applications.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYAVK.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can use "Find children" activity with upper level selector of the window that contains these links, and filter by elements with tag "a".

As a note, if you use this activity, you can set to find "Descendant", then you can find "childrens of childrens" with same activity.